# supervisord(node supervisor) 3.0b2 unable to upgrade to 3.1.2 Ubuntu 1404.1 LTS

Tags: node.js, supervisord

I am having trouble restarting Node.js running supervisord --version 3.00b2 therefore I am trying to upgrade to the latest release:
https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/releases/tag/3.1.2

This is the question: is this not possible, or?

I have tried with:

1. apt-get install supervisor
    
   Result: supervisor is already the newest version.
2. easy_install supervisor
   Result: After running "python setup.py install"
   Result: Processing dependencies for supervisor
   Finished processing dependencies for supervisor

But the version is still 3.0b2.

Extra information,answer if you feel like it:
I have seen issues with version 3.0b2 like supervisorctl reload giving 
error: , [Errno 2] 
in version 3.0a1 
https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/121

I am new to supervisor and was looking for a process manager for Node.js.

Second question: Is this the right tool or can you recumbent others?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to install supervisor 3.1.3 on Ubuntu 14.04.1 by dong:

```
sudo apt-get remove supervisor
```

to remove 3.0b2. Then:

```
sudo pip install supervisor
```

to install 3.1.3.

If you don't have pip installed:

```
sudo apt-get install python

sudo apt-get install pip
```

One caveat is that this installed supervisord in /usr/local/bin instead of  (I think) /usr/bin so I had to update my /etc/init.d/supervisor script to:

```
DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/supervisord
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The Ubuntu supervisor version is patched to make the syntax simpler, so be sure to test your commands!

Answer (score 1):

Installing the latest supervisor on ubuntu 14.04.5 I did the following:

```
apt-get install python-pip

pip install supervisor
```

now the script in /etc/init.d/supervisor is looking for supervisord and and supervisorctl in /usr/bin/ and you need to add a symlink from /usr/local/bin/supervisord to /usr/bin/supervisord and the same for supervisorctl

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/supervisorctl /usr/bin/supervisorctl
ln -s /usr/local/bin/supervisord /usr/bin/supervisord
```

now `/etc/init.d/supervisor start/restart` should work